# AWS CloudFormation: Get PathPart property of ApiGateway resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns, infrastructure-as-code

I describe my AWS resources in CloudFormation template and faced with next issue - I have SNS subscription with HTTPS protocol. Using that subscription I link SNS topic for CloudWatch alarms with API Gateway, which forwards these alarms to Slack webhook. In my CloudFormation template I already described API Gateway elements (REST API, resource and method):

```
Resources:
  AlarmRestApi:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    Properties:
      Name: "sns-to-slack"
      Description: "REST API for forwarding CloudWatch alarms to Slack"

  SlackAlarmsResource:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref "AlarmRestApi"
      ParentId: !GetAtt "AlarmRestApi.RootResourceId"
      PathPart: "slack-alarms"

  AlarmRestApiStage:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage"
    Properties:
      DeploymentId: !Ref "RestApiDeployment"
      RestApiId: !Ref "AlarmRestApi"
      StageName: "dev"
  ...
```

Currently I describe SNS topic and subscription, but I couldn't get PathPart attribute of 'SlackAlarmsResource' to avoid hardcode it in subscription template. With hardcoded resource value it look:

```
CloudWatchAlarmsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: "cloudwatch-alarms"
      TopicName: "cloudwatch-alarms"

  CloudWatchAlarmsSubcscription:
    Type: "AWS::SNS::Subscription"
    Properties:
      TopicArn: !Ref "CloudWatchAlarmsTopic"
      Endpoint: !Sub "https://${AlarmRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${AlarmRestApiStage}/slack-alarms"
      Protocol: https
      RawMessageDelivery: true
```

How can I get PathPart value ("slack-alarms") of API Gateway resource in SNS subscription endpoint property?

Comment: you can't because is PathPart is [not a returned value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-resource.html). You can pass a [parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) to both templates or use a [custom CF template that output the value to being used in other templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926728/how-to-refer-a-derived-variable-in-cloudformation)